# Is 早晚 included in 普通话？

Tags: topolect

I knew the term 早晚 today.

> [早晚    zǎo wǎn morning and evening / (dialect) some time in the future; some day](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%97%A9%E6%99%9A)

There is the literal "(dialect)" below (the whole line was quoted from the above link.)

I guess that 迟早 can also convey (almost) the same meaning but I also want to use 早晚 in front of Chineses. So the problem is that if the term 早晚 is not a subset of 普通话 then some my Chinese acquaintances might be 听不懂 when I use that term.

Can I use it naturally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context 早晚 can mean:

1. 早上和晚上 (morning and evening)

Example:

**早晚**服药; **早晚**放狗 (take medicine **in the morning and at night**; walk the dog **in the morning and at night**)

不分**早晚**地等 = 不分**日夜**地等 (waiting **day and night**)

2. 早 = soon; 晚 = late; 早晚 = sooner or later

Example:

经常醉驾**早晚**要出事 = 经常醉驾**迟早**要出事 (Frequent drunk driving will lead to accidents **sooner or later**)

俄乌战争**早晚**要分出胜负 = 俄乌战争**迟早**要分出胜负 (**Sooner or late**r, the war between Russia and Ukraine will be decided)

早晚 is more literary and 迟早 is more colloquial

**It all depends on the context, Mandarin or not**

Answer (score 1):

(1) One of the meanings of the word "早晚" is "someday in the future" or "sooner or later". "早晚" has the same meaning as "迟早". For example,

你不好好学习，早晚会后悔的。If you don't study hard, you will regret it sooner or later. (Used Google Translate)

A pretty rude statement from the gang fighting in movies and novels is that,

你给我等着，早晚找你算账。There will be retaliation sooner or later.

(2) "早晚" is frequently used by Chinese people in their daily life. It is a word in Standard Chinese or Mandarin 普通话. Therefore, I believe the remark (dialect) on your resource is not accurate.